# How can i save photo src in photo format using webapi

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api2

I have a photo source in the variable and I want to post it an API for save the photo in the server as image format.

Please help me out.

I was stuck from 2 days.

I am using angular js factory for save the image src
var imagecollection = theService.getData(keyValue[i]);

and I am using posting the src using Angularjs post method.

$scope.uploadFiles = function () {
        theService.sendData('odometerurl', $scope.odoimage);

```
    tempdata = {};

       // console.log(keyValue[i]);
        var imagecollection = theService.getData('odometerurl');
        // alert(imagecollection);
        var base64String = imagecollection;
    var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:54570/api/FileUpload/Base64ToImage',
        data: base64String,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    };

    // SEND THE FILES.
    $http(request)
        .success(function (d) {
         //   alert(d + ' Success');
        })
        .error(function (d) {
        //    alert(d + ' failed');
        });


}
```

But i have no idea how to post the image and save the image using webapi.

Please help me out.

Comment: where you have problem in your server side code or in your client side code.
if you have problem in client side that is in angular js photo uploading then defiantly you should have to look on ngupload module here is the link https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload

Comment: Simply i reduce an image size without loosing metadata.
 and now i have src in a varible like  
$scope.vinimage = $('.vin img').attr('src');
 . but i have to post the src convert into formdata.
    var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('img', $scope.vinimage);
and now i post the formdata using angular post to webApi
                 System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
            for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt <= hfc.Count - 1; iCnt++)
            {
                
         }